# Setup Synctex with Emacs in Windows with Sumatra PDF

Tags: emacs, windows, auctex, forward-inverse-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simpleton's guide to (…)TeX workflow with emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50827/a-simpletons-guide-to-tex-workflow-with-emacs)

I want to setup SyncTeX in GNU Emacs 23.3.1 with Auctex 11.86 to work with Sumatra PDF 2.0.1. I use Windows XP and MiKTeX 2.8. I've tried a lot of things but i can not make it work. There must be some wizard here that can help me :)

Comment: Does this answer help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51689/586

Comment: @TorbjørnT Yes, i finally did it!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Since that answerer have not answered this question you might want to adapt that to an answer to this question.