# AUCTeX – new commands recognized as such

Tags: macros, auctex

Many non-base commands, quite used today, are not recognized as such by AUCTeX. This is understandable as not everyone will use them, and not every time. I'm thinking about commands like `\enquote{...}`. Is there a way of making recognizing them—that is, of introducing new commands into the AUCTeX database? I've tried following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844936/emacs-auctex-custom-syntax-highlight) instructions to introduce new commands, but they don't work for me.

Comment: Do you mean to add commands such that they are known by and suggested by `C-c RET` and `C-c C-e`? If you only want fontification (e.g. syntax highlighting) for new commands see the heading `;; Fontification` in the .emacs example in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50919/5701

Comment: Thanks, N.N. If you would like to add a piece of the code as an answer, I'll acknowledge it as such.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are happy with *fontification* (as explained in http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-05/msg00236.html) you can add the following to your .emacs. It adds fontification for some macros, such as some from `biblatex`, `csquotes`, `cleveref` and `enumitem`. If you want to add or remove macros from the configuration it is easily done, just [check the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Fontification-of-macros.html).

```lisp
;; Fontification
;; http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-05/msg00236.html
;; http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Fontification-of-macros.html
(setq font-latex-match-reference-keywords
      '(
        ;; biblatex
        ("printbibliography" "[{")
        ("addbibresource" "[{")
        ;; Standard commands
        ;; ("cite" "[{")
        ("Cite" "[{")
        ("parencite" "[{")
        ("Parencite" "[{")
        ("footcite" "[{")
        ("footcitetext" "[{")
        ;; Style-specific commands
        ("textcite" "[{")
        ("Textcite" "[{")
        ("smartcite" "[{")
        ("Smartcite" "[{")
        ("cite*" "[{")
        ("parencite*" "[{")
        ("supercite" "[{")
        ;; Qualified citation lists
        ("cites" "[{")
        ("Cites" "[{")
        ("parencites" "[{")
        ("Parencites" "[{")
        ("footcites" "[{")
        ("footcitetexts" "[{")
        ("smartcites" "[{")
        ("Smartcites" "[{")
        ("textcites" "[{")
        ("Textcites" "[{")
        ("supercites" "[{")
        ;; Style-independent commands
        ("autocite" "[{")
        ("Autocite" "[{")
        ("autocite*" "[{")
        ("Autocite*" "[{")
        ("autocites" "[{")
        ("Autocites" "[{")
        ;; My custom cite commands
        ("posscite" "[{")
        ("Posscite" "[{")
        ("posscites" "[{")
        ("Posscites" "[{")
        ;; Text commands
        ("citeauthor" "[{")
        ("Citeauthor" "[{")
        ("citetitle" "[{")
        ("citetitle*" "[{")
        ("citeyear" "[{")
        ("citedate" "[{")
        ("citeurl" "[{")
        ;; Special commands
        ("fullcite" "[{")
        ;; cleveref
        ("cref" "{")
        ("Cref" "{")
        ("cpageref" "{")
        ("Cpageref" "{")
        ("cpagerefrange" "{")
        ("Cpagerefrange" "{")
        ("crefrange" "{")
        ("Crefrange" "{")
        ("labelcref" "{")))

(setq font-latex-match-textual-keywords
      '(
        ;; biblatex brackets
        ("parentext" "{")
        ("brackettext" "{")
        ("hybridblockquote" "[{")
        ;; Auxiliary Commands
        ("textelp" "{")
        ("textelp*" "{")
        ("textins" "{")
        ("textins*" "{")
        ;; subcaption
        ("subcaption" "[{")))

(setq font-latex-match-variable-keywords
      '(
        ;; amsmath
        ("numberwithin" "{")
        ;; enumitem
        ("setlist" "[{")
        ("setlist*" "[{")
        ("newlist" "{")
        ("renewlist" "{")
        ("setlistdepth" "{")
        ("restartlist" "{")
        ("crefname" "{")))
```