# Cleveref: AUCTeX and RefTeX set-up

Tags: cross-referencing, emacs, auctex, cleveref, reftex

How can I set up `cleveref` to work with AUCTeX and RefTeX?  I have tried the advice on [Emacs, RefTeX and Cleveref – can they work together?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15310/emacs-reftex-and-cleveref-can-they-work-together) but it didn't work.

Additionally, when I hit enter, `\ref{}` portion is always enclosed in `( )`.  How can I get rid of `( )` enclosing the `ref{}`?

I also checked out:

[AUCTeX – new commands recognized as such](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85849/auctex-new-commands-recognized-as-such/86119#86119)

this post but all the information is relatively old so maybe there is a newer answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the following code to your init file

```lisp
(eval-after-load
    "latex"
  '(TeX-add-style-hook
    "cleveref"
    (lambda ()
      (if (boundp 'reftex-ref-style-alist)
      (add-to-list
       'reftex-ref-style-alist
       '("Cleveref" "cleveref"
         (("\\cref" ?c) ("\\Cref" ?C) ("\\cpageref" ?d) ("\\Cpageref" ?D)))))
      (reftex-ref-style-activate "Cleveref")
      (TeX-add-symbols
       '("cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)))))
```

I've taken the value for `reftex-ref-style-alist` from this revision: http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/revision/112689

For the `\ref` enclosed in `( )`, add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
(setq reftex-label-alist '(AMSTeX))
```

as also suggested in the [RefTeX manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.html#SEC20) (see also [Emacs' RefTeX reftex-reference unconditionally surrounding `eq:...` reference with parens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276769/31416))

Comment: The code I posted works for me: if I press `C-c C-m cref RET`, I get `\cref`, not `\ref`, it's impossible you get a `\ref`.  Please explain better what's your problem and, if you can, post all AUCTeX/RefTeX related customizations in your `.emacs`.

Comment: @dustin I updated my answer, but you didn't specify that.

Comment: @dustin which version of AUCTeX and RefTeX are you using? Here: AUCTeX 11.87 and RefTeX shipped with Emacs 24.3. Do you set AUCTeX `TeX-parse-self` and `TeX-auto-save` variables to `t`?

Comment: See the first lines of AUCTeX manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html  If you want to exploit all AUCTeX features (in particular its ability to parse TeX documents) you have to set those variables to non-nil.  My code works in that case, that's the most common case among AUCTeX users.

Comment: If `TeX-parse-self` and `TeX-auto-save` are non nil, it must work. When you have a `\usepackage{cleveref}` in your document `cleveref` appears in `TeX-style-list` variable (check its value in your buffer) and the hook associated to `cleveref` is run, that is the hook I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Sorry if I insist but it must works, if doesn't work it's a bug in AUCTeX, and you should report it, or there is something tricky in your configuration.  Check the value of `TeX-active-styles` in the LaTeX buffer (the previous mentioned `TeX-style-list` doesn't exist, my fault): is `"cleveref"` present?  Check the value of `TeX-style-hook-list`: is the hook I wrote present?

Comment: In general you can view the value of a variable with `C-h v`, so `C-h v TeX-active-styles RET` and `C-h v TeX-style-hook-list RET` (you can use auto completion with TAB). These variables are buffer local, so you must issue those commands in the same buffer of the document you are editing.

Comment: We are going a bit off topic here, but those variables are correctly set, perhaps there is something wrong with your AUCTeX/RefTeX configuration. You can try starting Emacs with a clean `.emacs` except for setting `TeX-auto-save`, `TeX-parse-self` to `t` and the code I posted in the answer.

Comment: I just uninstalled TeXlive2012 and installed 2013 and now your solutions works.  I don't know how or why that would effect it though.

Comment: Me neither `:-|`  That should be completely unrelated to the distribution you are using.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me because the "cleveref" style isn't being set (it isn't in `TeX-active-styles`. I include the package with `\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}` in my master document, but `reftex-ref-style-alist` is never updated. How should the "cleveref" style become active?

Comment: @robin  Do you have [parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Parsing-Files) enabled?

Comment: @giordana I think so yes: `TeX-parse-self`, `TeX-auto-save` and `reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX` are set to `t`

Comment: @giordano robin appears to have a subfile-based project, judging from "in my master document". I seem to run into the same issues as robin, as I also have a subfile based project and the `cleverref` style does not get activated… :/ Is there a way to forcefully enable the style?