# Emacs' RefTeX reftex-reference unconditionally surrounding `eq:...` reference with parens

Tags: reftex

Whenever I insert a reference to a label starting with `eq:` RefTeX seems to decide to surround it with (), e.g. it will insert `(\ref{eq:1))` into the buffer. This is particularly annoying if I am using cleveref, because `(\cref{eq:1})` is not at all right.

It is implied in [one other place](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119273/12432) (the only place I've seen it mentioned) that this surprising/unexpected behaviour and may be due to my own customisations (of which there aren't many at all)... but if I start emacs with `emacs -Q` to disable all of them, it still occurs for both of the built-in reference formats (`\ref` and `\pageref`).

I'm using Emacs 24.5 with RefTex 24.4 on Ubuntu.

It would be very nice to stop/control this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of testing, I stand corrected (with respect what I said in the answer you mentioned): what you describe is indeed the default behavior, but of course can be changed.  If you want to use `amsmath` style of referecen, add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
(setq reftex-label-alist '(AMSTeX))
```

as also suggested in the [RefTeX manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.html#SEC20).

If in particular you want to use `\eqref{}` when `cleveref` is not loaded, and not to have anyway the parentheses around `\ref{}` in documents loading `cleveref` package add the following code to your init file (it's based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119273/12432), already mentioned in the question)

```lisp
(setq reftex-label-alist '(AMSTeX)) ;; as before, but will be changed in cleveref document, see below

(eval-after-load
    "latex"
  '(TeX-add-style-hook
    "cleveref"
    (lambda ()
      (if (boundp 'reftex-ref-style-alist)
          (add-to-list
           'reftex-ref-style-alist
           '("Cleveref" "cleveref"
             (("\\cref" ?c) ("\\Cref" ?C) ("\\cpageref" ?d) ("\\Cpageref" ?D)))))
      (reftex-ref-style-activate "Cleveref")
      (set (make-variable-buffer-local 'reftex-label-alist)
       '(("equation"  ?e "eq:" "~\\ref{%s}" t
          (regexp "equations?" "eqs?\\." "eqn\\." "Gleichung\\(en\\)?"  "Gl\\."))))
      (TeX-add-symbols
       '("cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)))))
```

Comment: Hm, so this improves/changes things somewhat: instead of `(...)`, it uses `eqref` for `eq:...` labels (even if I try to use non-`ref` reference formats like `pageref` or the `cref` one I've defined).

Comment: @huon See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm still not sure that's really the right thing. I want RefTeX to understand that when I explicitly request the `\cref` format (added as you suggest in the answer that I linked in my question), it should just insert `\cref` instead of trying to guess what I mean with the heuristics that don't apply to the more intelligent referencing packages. I also don't really want to *force* the `\cref` format (not all the documents I work on use it).

Comment: (Lastly, it's not just the `e` key: this seems to be driven by the `eq:` prefix, for instance, if I use space to see all the labels in my file, RefTeX still inserts parens/`eqref` if I choose an `eq:...` label.)

Comment: Indeed `reftex-typekey-to-format-alist` is relevant not only when the `e` type of labels is selected, but every time a label with `eq:` prefix is chosen.  If in a document with `cleveref` you always want to you only `\cref` you only need to set `reftex-label-alist` to `nil` there (add `(set (make-variable-buffer-local 'reftex-label-alist) nil)` in the hook of the other question, after `reftex-ref-style-activate`)

Comment: Ok. If I use your next suggestion, that still seems to insert parens, e.g. my reftex-related config looks like https://gist.github.com/huonw/2b8cf14507217760cd78 but using `c` (i.e. cleveref) with an `eq:` label still has surrounding parens. (`reftex-label-alist` is indeed `nil`, per `C-h v`, but that also tells me the global value is `nil` so that doesn't seem to have changed the situation.)

Comment: But did you also add the line `(setq reftex-label-alist '(AMSTeX))` in your init file?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise it was meant to be an addition to that. However, that doesn't actually change anything: I still get `(\cref{eq:1})`, i.e. parens.

Comment: I guess you didn't put the `(add-to-list 'reftex-typekey-to-format-alist '("e" . "~\\ref{%s}"))` line your init file, either.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried it, and it doesn't seem to do anything: parens are still included.

Comment: Having a look to your configuration would help now.

Comment: In https://gist.github.com/huonw/a7615ddb1dd2868f952a , I started with a plain `init.el` file with each of the suggestions (as I've understood them), and tested them, and none worked. Do you see different behaviour? (I guess it's not the *worst* to have equations use `\eqref` and everything else use `cref`: I can just alias the former to the latter, but it'd be nice to not have to do it.)

Comment: RefTeX's code is somewhat evil, the trick with `reftex-typekey-to-format-alist` seems to work only in some conditions (the ones I was testing, of course).  I updated the answer, should work now.

Comment: Awesome, `\cref` is now inserted without parens! However it seems to be unconditionally running the cleveref style hook, even in a document without cleveref. See [`init6.el`](https://gist.github.com/huonw/a7615ddb1dd2868f952a#file-init6-el).

Comment: So if you open a document without `cleveref` package, the variable `TeX-active-styles` contains `"cleveref"` (issue `C-h v TeX-active-styles RET` in that buffer)?

Comment: Oh, the problem was I was using the same document, just adding/removing the `\usepackage{cleveref}` and then closing/reopening emacs, but the caching in `auto/*.el` meant it was sticking with the old list of packages. It works fine if I delete that file, or if I use separate files like the gist suggested. Thanks so much for working through this with me!

Comment: You just need to issue `C-c C-n` to force reparsing of the file `;-)`