# How to be productive with latex in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am using the default latex mode for Emacs. I haven't tried Auctex yet.

I am making mistakes here and there and spending a lot of time, while switching between editing tex files in emacs and viewing pdf files in evince for checking correctness.

Ideally, I hope that

1. I can go quickly from where it is wrong in pdf files to where the
   corresponding lines are in tex files. I spend too much time in switching to and from viewing pdf files and  searching
   in tex files.
2. there are  ways that can help me easily read and understand the
   latex code for math formulas, with less need to switch to view pdf
   files in evince. That cost me too much time too.
3. More or you name it, which can help to improve productivity.

I appreciate if you have advice, whether it is an IDE working in Emacs, or some latex code style that help with readability.

Btw,

- I almost always use Emacs in terminal mode, and I seldom use XEmacs because XEmacs is a little slower. Is that be a reason that I am not productive?
- Is there a more productive way than coding in Emacs?

Comment: Use AUCTeX.  It has (bundled with it) something called 'preview', which will let you previous math environments nearly on-the-fly.  Also, I feel like this should be community-wiki since an answer will more-or-less be a jumble of links and small tips (rather than a canonical solution).

Comment: For (1), setup synctex.  I solely use emacs from the bash terminal as well but I feel productive.

Comment: There are many useful tips at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50827/a-simpletons-guide-to-tex-workflow-with-emacs (of which this question may be more or less a duplicate).

Comment: If you use Emacs in a terminal emulator (I do as well), then consider using it in conjuction with a terminal multiplexer like [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).  I find 'embedding' an emacs session in tmux a very useful way to go.  I also strongly recommend AUCTeX.  Synctex is no doubt useful, but I have never bothered with it.

Comment: Any answer to this question will be opinion based. So this question should be closed or transform in community-wiki.