# Indexing support similar to RefTeX

Tags: indexing, editors, mac, reftex

I've been a happy TeXShop user for many years and have hardly felt that it missed anything crucial.

But since I'm doing more and more indexing from scratch, I started to look for a tool, that will assist me in the process of *extending* and *systemizing* my entries. I am not thinking of macros and shortcuts to add the actual commands to the code. TeXShop can easily be configured to do this.

I'd mainly need a handy way to reuse information that I've already figured out the last time an index-item occurred:
E.g. when the texts mentions "king Charles" and I mark the name with `\index{Charles}` I'd like to get a list with all previously marked Charleses and a quick way to choose and paste the whole `\index{Charles 2@Charles II, dit \emph{le Chauve}, (823--877), king of the Franks, Holy Roman Emperor}` that I painstakingly copied from Wikipedia when he was mentioned the first time.

I've seen that [RefTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.pdf) seems to offer this feature and I might end up following in [Brent's footsteps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50827/a-simpletons-guide-to-tex-workflow-with-emacs?lq=1) and switch to emacs if I have to – but I'd really prefer not to.

**Is there a dedicated TeX-editor other than emacs which supports the described feature or are there add-ons or scripts that could be used to extend one of the editors?**

Information about other RefTeX-like features in other editors would be welcome, but are secondary to me.

Comment: texstudio's autocompletion for bib(la)tex works very much in a way that I'd love to see for indices. I have added this as a [feature request on their project site](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1222/). Whoever feels like this would be a good addition, might want to vote and/or comment there.

Answer (score 3):

Well, indexing is a very critical thing.  For an excellent index is very often an person hired to create the index, because s/he can do it much more better than a program can.

I do not know an editor (except Emacs) having such a feature, but there is a phyton program called [indexmeister](https://sourceforge.net/projects/indexmeister/) that seems to be able to help you. It has two program parts, one for searching the LaTeX code for words worth to be indexed and a second helping you to add the wanted index entrys ...

But please see I have no experiance with it because I create an index by my own ...

Comment: Thanks for the hint! indexmeister is a very interesting tool, especially if one quickly wants to build a name-index. For other purposes, namely an index of themes or concepts, its approach doesn't work too well. Even though I like its very simple interface, the lack of syntax-coloring is also problematic. In my case I'd also need better support for other languages than English (choose more than one dictionary, proper Unicode-handling).